# webapi 404 not found when calling from react with post action

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following controller action

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Tenant/SetTenantActive")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive(string tenantid)
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            var allTenants = await tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.TenantDomainUrl != null).ToListAsync();
            foreach(Tenant ten  in allTenants)
            {
                ten.Active = false;
                await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(ten);
            }

            var tenant = await tenantStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == tenantid);
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            tenant.Active = true;
            var result = await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(tenant);

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

And my react code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListTenants extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }



    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.ClientId,
                    ClientId: row.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret: row.ClientSecret,
                    Id: row.Id,
                    SiteCollectionTestUrl: row.SiteCollectionTestUrl,
                    TenantDomainUrl: row.TenantDomainUrl
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Client Id',
                    dataIndex: 'ClientId',
                    key: 'ClientId'
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Collection TestUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                    key: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tenant DomainUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                    key: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                }
        ];

        // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
        const rowSelection = {
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                if(selectedRows[0].key != undefined){
                    console.log(selectedRows[0].key);

                    const options = {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: {tenantid:selectedRows[0].key},
                    };

                    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive", options)
                        .then(response =>{
                        if(response.status === 200){
                            Notification(
                                'success',
                                'Tenant created',
                                ''
                                );
                        }else{
                            throw "error";
                        }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                        Notification(
                            'error',
                            'Tenant not created',
                            error
                            );
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            getCheckboxProps: record => ({
                type: Radio
            }),
        };

        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

focus only on the onchange event,

And the screenshot:
[image]

And it looks like the request gets to the webapi (I attached the debugger)

[image]

Update:

Basically If I dont put FromBody I need to send the parameter via querystring.
However if I put from Body and I send the parameter in the body, its received null on the webapi

Comment: Your route setup looks correct to me at first glance.  I notice that you're returning a NotFound if `tenantStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == tenantid)` returns null.  Verify that this query is actually succeeding.  Chances are that this query is actually failing and that you're returning a 404 as a result.

Comment: but its not even hitting the breakpoint when I attach the debugger

Comment: Are you able to hit the api directly using Postman, Insomnia, curl, or some other REST testing tool?  Trying to figure out if it's an API issue or an issue in your client code.

Comment: I figured it out, basically I need to create a post request, but with querystring parameters like this: /SetTenantActive?tenantid=1.  However, my question remains, why its not accepting the data in the body?

Comment: @LuisValencia 
Try adding `[FromBody]` before input parameter like this: `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody]string tenantid)`

Comment: I added it but I get null on the webapi, the value is correctly set in the frontend, but received as null
                    const options = {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: {"tenantid":selectedRows[0].key},
                    };

Comment: @LuisValencia Try wrapping your tenantId value in double quotes like this: `options = { method: 'post', body: {"tenantid": "\"" + selectedRows[0].key + "\"" }, }`

Comment: thanks but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [FromBody] before your input parameter in your action method like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody] string tenantid)
```

Then, convert your selected row key into string

```
const options = {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: { tenantid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }
                    };
```

Comment: I already did, but in the webapi the parameter is received as null

Comment: when I debug I can see the options const is set correctly, will upload an screenshot soon

Comment: am I missing content type json or something?

Comment: The issue is tenantid needs to be interpreted as string thats why I suggested to add .tostring()

Comment: In the network tab of developer tools, check the request payload of your POST api call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177676/discussion-between-luis-valencia-and-mohsin-mehmood).